# Weird MLFeatureValue response from https request

Tags: swift, https, compiler-errors, swift4

I'm having an issue/bug? where my https response returns JSON, as it should, but when i decode it, I'm suddenly told it is of type 'MLFeatureValue'?

Imported libraries:

- Foundation
- AVKit
- UIKit
- AVFoundation
- Vision

Using:

- Swift 4
- Xcode 9.2
- Project is ejected from react-native '0.54.3'

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g59Q4.png)

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=fancyApiKey;)")!)

request.httpBody = jsonData
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { requestData, requestResponse, error in

  let parsedResult = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: requestData!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
  print("data", parsedResult)

  guard let data = parsedResult["responses"] as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
```

> From the 'guard let data' line I get an error: "Cast from 'MLFeatureValue?!' to unrelated type '[String : AnyObject] always fails."

I have no idea where the 'MLFeatureValue' comes from, since I have nothing regarding machine learning imported in the file or even the project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have imported Vision. Vision uses a few ML classes and models. Please check out Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision). 
Still not sure how Xcode is doing this. A workaround can be that while parsing you can use `Any` in place of `AnyObject`, or you can be more specific about your data which is expected to come in response.

Comment: I have solved the issue by now. Thank you for taking your your time to answer though

Comment: Was some kind of bug. Cleaned and closed everything. Seemed to the trick

Comment: okay, @Carl-JohanBeurling. Didn't work for me. I am using the same by changing the parse type. It's working that way.